# Phonons in quantum dots

Tags: phonons, quantum-dots

If my understanding is correct, quantum dots are tiny crystals where the confined electronic degrees of freedom have discrete energy levels. In this paper [Phys. Rev. B 65, 195313 (2002)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.65.195313), and many others, electron-phonon coupling is discussed in the context of quantum dots. I understand what is meant by a phonon in the context of macroscopic crystals, but what is the meaning of a "phonon in a quantum dot".

I am guessing, but not sure, that since a quantum dot is a tiny crystal we can also define phonon as excitation of the lattice degrees of freedom, with the difference that their energy will be discrete due to confinement.

Comment: Since this question hasn't received much interest, you might want to try [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) with the "terminology" tag. That community works exclusively on advanced-level questions like these, and doesn't contain any high-school level homework questions, so the community might be more likely to answer your question.